# SQL Server Query Size of Results Set

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there anyway in SQL Server to determine the size in MEGS of data that a query returned in  a query from Mgmt Studio in the Result Set?

Comment: Thanks guys, I trying this against SQL Azure so I will give client stats ago tomorrow!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can turn on client statistics (Query menu, Include Client Statistics) which gives number of bytes returned from the server when the query is executed.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed and helped me get what I needed very quickly.  Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Create a table with query results and run sp_spaceused against it.

```
SELECT *
INTO tablename
FROM ...

Exec sp_spaceused 'tablename'

DROP TABLE tablename
```

Comment: You can also choose to include client statistics and check "Bytes received from server" but i am not sure it counts only data bytes.

Comment: looks like you beat me to it - the # of bytes is probably total number of bytes including protocol overhead.  Whilst it might not map directly to # of bytes in resultset, it could prove useful.

Comment: Thying to help a peer my friend, not to compete. Your idea is very good - the overhead normally is not too much. Running the query from the server seems to be closer to the "tuth" since I get less bytes.

Comment: likewise, not competing - I think we both posted client stats within a minute of each other!  :)  Enjoy!

Comment: I like this approach. The huge downside that many people ignore is that using just client stats you need to wait for data over the wire that can add a lot of time before you get an answer.  With this approach I had an answer within minutes for some data warehouse sizing that I needed to perform